# Calculating the SUM of (Quantity*Price) from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sum

I have two tables as follows

`PRODUCT` table

```
Id | Name | Price
```

And an `ORDERITEM` table

```
Id | OrderId | ProductId | Quantity
```

What I'm trying to do is, calculate the subtotal price for each product (Quantity*Price) then SUM the TOTAL value for the entire order..

I'm trying something like this

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Quantity * (select Price from Product where Id = Id)) as qty
FROM OrderItem o
WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
```

But of course that doesn't work :)

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT:** I only want to show the grand total for the entire order, so basically the sum of Quantity*Price for every row in OrderItem. Here's some sample data.

***Sample Data***

**TABLE Product**

```
Id     Name            Price  
1      Tomatoes        20.09    
4      Cucumbers       27.72    
5      Oranges         21.13    
6      Lemons          20.05
7      Apples          12.05
```

**Table OrderItem**

```
Id         OrderId        ProductId        Quantity
151        883            1                22
152        883            4                11
153        883            5                8
154        883            6                62
```

M

Comment: Do you want two columns - subtotal per product and total per order?  Your query only has one column...

Comment: It's best when asking for advice on SQL queries to include a small amount of sample data (even if only 3 or 4 rows) and the expected outcome from the query.

Comment: Hi Tom - have now added sample data.

Comment: Thx for the example data, but what are you expected for output?

Comment: Just a Grand Total for the Order, so I just want to return 1 value - the SUM of Quantity*Price for each OrderItem, filtered by the OrderId. In simplest terms, I want SUM(Quantity*Price) Where OrderId = 883

Comment: See my update, but without an example all we had is your original query which used `ORDERITEM.id` rather than `ORDERITEM.orderid`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT oi.orderid,
         SUM(oi.quantity * p.price) AS grand_total,
    FROM ORDERITEM oi
    JOIN PRODUCT p ON p.id = oi.productid
   WHERE oi.orderid = @OrderId
GROUP BY oi.orderid
```

Mind that if either `oi.quantity` or `p.price` is null, the SUM will return NULL.

Comment: +1 However I think the statement "if either `oi.quantity` or `p.price` is null then SUM will return NULL" is a little unclear. Sum will only return null if the value for _all_ rows of a group is null. Otherwise sum ignores null. So quantity or price would have to be null for each row in a group for that group to be null.

Comment: Hey @OMG Ponies, your query returns a subtotal for each OrderItem row, rather than the grand total for all rows.. Almost like the SUM is being ignored :/

Answer (score 1):

i think this - including null value = 0

```
 SELECT oi.id, 
         SUM(nvl(oi.quantity,0) * nvl(p.price,0)) AS total_qty 
    FROM ORDERITEM oi 
    JOIN PRODUCT p ON p.id = oi.productid 
   WHERE oi.orderid = @OrderId 
GROUP BY oi.id
```

Comment: `NVL` is Oracle specific - COALESCE would be a better choice.

Comment: There is no reason to do COALESCE (or NVL) on each input. You could: `coalesce(sum(oi.quantity * p.price), 0) as total_qty`.

Comment: This doesn't return the Grand Total, but rather the subtotal for each OrderItem row, same as @OMG Ponies' answer above..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is along the lines of what you're looking for. It appears that you want to see the orderid, the subtotal for each item in the order and the total amount for the order.

```
select o1.orderID, o1.subtotal, sum(o2.UnitPrice * o2.Quantity) as order_total from
(
    select o.orderID, o.price * o.qty as subtotal
    from product p inner join orderitem o on p.ProductID= o.productID
    where o.orderID = @OrderId
)as o1
inner join orderitem o2 on o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID
group by o1.orderID, o1.subtotal
```

Comment: Hey @mpminnich, I just need the grand total for all OrderItems, so basically the SUM of Quantity*Price

Answer (score 0):

```
select orderID, sum(subtotal) as order_total from
(
    select orderID, productID, price, qty, price * qty as subtotal
    from product p inner join orderitem o on p.id = o.productID
    where o.orderID = @orderID
) t
group by orderID
```

Comment: Hi @Beth - I get a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'."

Comment: sorry, needed to add an alias after the )

Comment: This returns every row in the OrderItem table, and the order_total and subtotal are identical, so SUM again isn't doing it's job :/

Comment: sorry again, didn't know you only wanted the grand total and I needed to remove columns from the inner query you don't want broken down.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as Marko and come across a solution like this:

```
/*Create a Table*/
CREATE TABLE tableGrandTotal
(
columnGrandtotal int
)

/*Create a Stored Procedure*/
CREATE PROCEDURE GetGrandTotal
AS

/*Delete the 'tableGrandTotal' table for another usage of the stored procedure*/
DROP TABLE tableGrandTotal

/*Create a new Table which will include just one column*/
CREATE TABLE tableGrandTotal
(
columnGrandtotal int
)

/*Insert the query which returns subtotal for each orderitem row into tableGrandTotal*/
INSERT INTO tableGrandTotal
    SELECT oi.Quantity * p.Price AS columnGrandTotal
        FROM OrderItem oi
        JOIN Product p ON oi.Id = p.Id

/*And return the sum of columnGrandTotal from the newly created table*/    
SELECT SUM(columnGrandTotal) as [Grand Total]
    FROM tableGrandTotal
```

And just simply use the GetGrandTotal Stored Procedure to retrieve the Grand Total :)

```
EXEC GetGrandTotal
```