# Find Cost from Product ID in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, relationship

I'm trying to create a calculated field for "Total Cost" of an order in MS Access. My tables are related as below:

[image: Table Relationships]

So I want to be able to set Orders: Cost to a calculate field where it takes the associated with each of Items 1,2,3,4 and 5 and sums them together.

Also, is there a more flexible way to add multiple products to each order without having multiple item columns?

Thanks in advance!

(I'm very new to this, apologies if I've missed out anything critical)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have highlighted, there is a fundamental problem with the way your tables are structured. In order to answer your question I suggest that you adjust your table schema first.

I'll therefore answer your second question, first:

> is there a more flexible way to add multiple products to each order without having multiple item columns?

Yes. Generally you'll want to use a second table to store your order items in. This type of table is typically called a 'bridge table' and it will allow you to store an unlimited number of items for each order. Let's call this table `Order Items`.

As an aside, I'm assuming your tables Products, Products_1, Products_2, Products_3 and Products_4 are all interfaces to the same table? Rather than being 5 tables all containing duplicates of your product data. I'll come back to this later.

Let's restructure your tables to look like this:

[image: New table schema]

Notice our new bridge table `Order Items`. To store order items in here, simply create a record for each product that the order contains, making reference to the Product ID and the associated Order ID.

## An Example Order

### Data

`Orders` table:

```
+----------+------------+------+
| Order ID | Order Date | Cost |
+----------+------------+------+
|        1 | 2015-04-25 | —    |
+----------+------------+------+
```

**Note:** ignore the cost field for now. I'll get to that in a bit.

`Order Items` table:

```
+----------+------------+
| Order ID | Product ID |
+----------+------------+
|        1 |          2 |
|        1 |          3 |
|        1 |          5 |
+----------+------------+
```

`Products` table:

```
+------------+---------+------+-------+
| Product ID | Product | Type | Price |
+------------+---------+------+-------+
|          1 | Hat     | —    |     5 |
|          2 | Scarf   | —    |    10 |
|          3 | Gloves  | —    |    12 |
|          4 | Coat    | —    |    50 |
|          5 | Boots   | —    |    25 |
+------------+---------+------+-------+
```

### Explanation

In the above example data, an order was placed on 25th April 2015. The order was for 3 products:

- Scarf
- Gloves
- Boots

By utilising an `Order Items` bridge table, we're able to store information about the products ordered in a more flexible format. The big advantage of this over your original database schema is that you're no longer limited to 5 items per order.

Now if my earlier assumption about the multiple product tables was *wrong*, then this new schema will give you an added advantage since you'll no longer need to duplicate your product data across 5 tables. You should never have to duplicate data in a database - the goal is to always have a 'single source of truth'. So your product data should only ever be stored in one place, and *never* duplicated into multiple tables.

This is what you'd call a 'normalised' database schema.

## So how about that cost calculation?

Well I have to admit, I'm no expert with MS Access. I have more experience with MySQL. So I'll try and help as much as possible.

Firstly - everything I say here will be based on the new table structure that I proposed above. Cost calculation for your original table structure will be different (and probably more complicated!)

One of the advantages of using a database is that you can dynamically query and perform calculations against your data. One such calculation would be the total order cost. MS Access will provide a function to dynamically calculate the total cost for an order based on the prices of the associated products. Since this can be calculated dynamically, there is no need for you to store this value in your database.

Remember what I said earlier about having a 'single source of truth' in your database? This applies here too. There's no need to store the calculated total of your order, because you'll end up having to re-calculate it every time an order item is changed. It would be redundant because it can be calculated dynamically by MS Access.

An example SQL query containing the order total could look like this:

```
SELECT
    `Orders`.*, SUM(`Products`.`price`) AS `Cost`
FROM
    `Orders`
LEFT JOIN `Order Items` ON (
    `Orders`.`Order ID` = `Order Items`.`Order ID`
)
LEFT JOIN `Products` ON (
    `Order Items`.`Product ID` = `Products`.`Product ID`
)
GROUP BY
    `Orders`.`Order ID`
```

Here I'm using the `SUM()` function to calculate the total of all product prices associated with an order. The `GROUP BY` operator is used to lump together all products associated with an individual order. And of course it's all tied together with 2 joins: `Orders -> Order Items` and `Order Items -> Products`.

In summary - although you're already on the right track, you need to change your database structure slightly. The new database structure is normalised and will allow you to perform lookups and easily calculate total order costs.

Hope that helps.

---

## Next steps (optional)

Once you've conquered the basic problem, you might be interested in taking things a step further.

One thing which you may have overlooked is that people can order multiple of the same product. Taking my above example, what if we wanted *2 scarves* in our order rather than 1? There's currently no way for you to store a quantity against each product in an order.

What you'll want to do is add a `Quantity` field to your `Order Items` table. Therefore, our new example order items table would look like this:

`Order Items` table:

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| Order ID | Product ID | Quantity |
+----------+------------+----------+
|        1 |          2 |        2 |
|        1 |          3 |        1 |
|        1 |          5 |        1 |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

From this you can see the order contains 2 scarves, 1 pair of gloves, and 1 pair of boots.

### Calculating total with quantity

This new quantity field will require a change in the way you calculate the total order cost. We will now need to do Quantity × Product Price, and sum them all together to get the order total.

[This SO post may be of some help for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506332/calculating-the-sum-of-quantityprice-from-2-different-tables) Essentially you'll want to use something like the following (**UNTESTED!**):

```
SELECT
    `Orders`.*, SUM(`Products`.`price` * `Order Items`.`Quantity`) AS `Cost`
FROM
    `Orders`
LEFT JOIN `Order Items` ON (
    `Orders`.`Order ID` = `Order Items`.`Order ID`
)
LEFT JOIN `Products` ON (
    `Order Items`.`Product ID` = `Products`.`Product ID`
)
GROUP BY
    `Orders`.`Order ID`
```

Notice that we are now multiplying price and quantity in order to calculate the `Cost` field.

### Changes in product price

Another thing to consider for the future is whether your product prices will change. When my example order is placed, gloves cost 12 ($/£/etc). If the product price increases after my order was placed, we no longer have a record of the price that was paid at the time the order was placed.

I feel like I'm jumping way ahead now, so I'll leave this as something for you to think about. If you need help with this you should probably post a new question.

Comment: You sir, are a genuine second coming of the messiah. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your design is not "normalized".

Your table "orders" should be split into two tables, like this:

**Table "Orders":**

- Order ID
- Order Date
- Cost (What is this field for?)

**Table "Ordered Items":**

- Order ID
- Product ID

So, "Ordered Items" can contain an unlimited list of items ordered. And you can then very easily create any kinds of sums and other calculations.

Comment: Cost is there to hold the total cost of each order. How would I then have mutiple products associated with each order ID?

Comment: Probably, you should store the cost of each single item also in table "Ordered Items".

Comment: The cost of each individual item is already stored under products?

Comment: Well, then why do you store the costs with the orders at all?

Comment: Because I want the TOTAL cost of each order, calculated from the sum of the costs of each individual item

Comment: OK, but then it seems that you can calculate the total within a query. It would be good practice to remove this field at all, and rather to create a query, which will output the total costs as a calculated field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76260/discussion-between-james-hughes-and-georg-scholz).

Comment: I think it should be public, so everyone has benefits from it.

Answer (score 0):

> apologies if I've missed out anything critical

You did. You'll have to normalize your data (bing/google on this) - inserting a table holding the order lines. Then you will have one relation between this an the orders table and another one between the order lines and products.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is wrong. I suggest that you read some tutorials about `database normalisation` and correct your design.
You could also locate/download the infamous Northwind database that used to be delivered with Access as a sample. It is a usable and decently designed Orders database, that you could use as a starting point.